# Проблема с созданием шаблона для регулярного выражения в Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Всем Здравствуйте! У меня стоит задача написать скрипт в Python, который получает на вход txt файл с n количеством строк и должен будет отбирать необходимые мне строки и цифры, затем добавлять их в отдельные списки и на выходе уже формировать таблицу в excel и сохранять ее на компьютере.

Пример записей из txt файла следующий (копирую в точности как представлено в файле, с пробелами, другими знаками и т.д.):

```
Школа вокала | Music School 21:05

Новая заявка по форме: Филиал 1

Сообщество: https://vk.com/music_school

Пользователь: https://vk.com/ivanov123

Дата отправки: сегодня в 21:05

Вопрос: Имя

Ответ: Иван

Вопрос: Номер телефона

Ответ: +7 (999) 111-11-11

Вопрос: Что для вас пение? (отвечать не обязательно)

Ответ: Хочу проработать свой тембр голоса!
```

Далее последовательность строк повторяется в том же порядке По заданию мне необходимо отбирать следующие данные:

```
после строки: "Вопрос: Имя" \n "Ответ:" (забираю имя)
после строки: "Вопрос: Номер телефона" \n "Ответ:" (забираю номер телефона)
после строки: "Вопрос: Что для вас пение? (отвечать не обязательно)"\n "Ответ:" (забираю все, что будет после этого)
```

По пункту 3 информация может быть разной, как в строке "Вопрос:", так и соответственно и в строке где ответ. Также некоторые данные, которые мне нужно будет забирать могут и вовсе отсутствовать, так что мне нужно, что после итерации порядок сохранения записей не сбился (к примеру, номер телефона сдвинулся на другое имя и т.д.).

Проблема заключается в том, что после запуска скрипта данные в таблицу не сохраняются (он пустой сохраняется). Пошарил в интернете, подкинули идею воспользоваться регулярными выражениями и создать патерны для сортировки строк. Патерны я проверял с помощью сервиса https://regex101.com/. Но результата пока нужного нет. Надеюсь кто-нибудь сможет помочь мне в этом вопросе!

## Собственно сам код:

```
import openpyxl
import re


def parcing(lines, path):

# Списки для хранения данных
users = []
names = []
phone_numbers = []
directions = []

# Регулярные выражения

user_regex = r"Пользователь:\s*(.*)"
name_regex = r"Вопрос:\s*Имя\s+Ответ:\s*(.*)"
phone_regex = r"Вопрос:\s*Номер телефона\s+Ответ:\s*(.*)"
direction_regex = "Вопрос:\s*Номер телефона\s+Ответ:\s*(.*)\s+Вопрос: (.*)\s*Ответ:\s*(.*)"
count = 0
# Обработка строк
for line in lines:
    # Поиск и извлечение значений с помощью регулярных выражений
    user_match = re.fullmatch(user_regex, line)
    name_match = re.fullmatch(name_regex, line)
    phone_match = re.fullmatch(phone_regex, line)
    direction_match = re.fullmatch(direction_regex, line)
    if user_match:
        user = user_match.group(1)
        users.append(user)
    elif name_match:
        name = name_match.group(1)
        names.append(name)
    elif phone_match:
        phone_number = phone_match.group(1)
        phone_numbers.append(phone_number)
    elif direction_match:
        direction = direction_match.group(3)
        directions.append(direction)
    count += 1
print(f'Записей обработано: {count}')
print(f'Кол-во записей: Пользователь: {len(users)}, Имя: {len(names)}, Телефон: {len(phone_numbers)}, Направление: {len(directions)}')
# Создание и заполнение Excel таблицы
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = 'Data'
# Заголовки столбцов
ws.append(['Пользователь', 'Имя', 'Номер телефона', 'Описание'])

# Заполнение данными
for user, name, phone_number, direction in zip(users, names, phone_numbers, directions):
    ws.append([user, name, phone_number, direction])

# Сохранение файла
wb.save(path)


file_path = 'путь к файлу с данными'
output_path = 'путь сохранения итогового файла'

try:

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = file.readlines()
parcing(text, output_path)

except UnicodeDecodeError as error:

print(f"Ошибка при декодировании текста из файла: {error}")

finally:

print('Сохранение данных прошло успешно!')
```

Comment: Конкретно на этом тексте можно сделать так: https://regex101.com/r/xUxUlN/1